# Map-reduce on more than one keys

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, bigdata

**Problem**

We have records, say r<sub>i</sub> where i = 0,..., n.  n can be large (in tens of billions).

Every record has a number of keys, k<sub>ij</sub> where j = 0,..., m.  m is small (say 20)

We say, r<sub>p</sub> = r<sub>q</sub>, if k<sub>p0</sub> = k<sub>q0</sub>, k<sub>p1</sub> = k<sub>q1</sub>, …, **or**, k<sub>pm</sub> = k<sub>qm</sub>

That is, records are equal, if at least one their keys are equal. We need to find such sets of records and generate unique ids for those sets.

**Approach**

Run m map-reduce jobs, where each job reduces on one key.

So, for job i, mapper emits (r<sub>p</sub>, k<sub>i</sub>) and reducer gets ({r<sub>1</sub>,...,r<sub>p</sub>}, k<sub>i</sub>)

At the end of all the m jobs, we will have sets of records that have one equal key.

S<sub>k</sub> = {r<sub>l</sub>}

We expect k to less than n but still could be in hundreds of millions, and l to be a small number (say between 2 to 5000)

To get our final results, we will need to merge the above sets which have at least one member in common.

I have the following questions:

1. How to efficiently merge these sets?
2. Alternatively, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: How about hashing Key1-10?

Comment: BTW, I realized that running multi-step map-reduce is not going to work. @Ayush what do you mean by hashing k1-10?  Have one "super key"?  That is not going to work either. Equality of super key will not mean equality either of the key.

Comment: I edited my question to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it is a ConnectedComponent problem and have well known solutions.